# Dante with Kerberos configuration across sites

Tags: linux, kerberos, socks, dante

I have a requirement to host a socks proxy in a central location, using Dante. What I've been asked to do is connect remote clients to it across the internet, they'll pass through a gateway routing device that will forward HTTP traffic to Dante, in effect making it transparent.

It also needs to be encrypted, what I understand from the Dante documentation is that to encrypt between server and client GSSAPI should be used.

So, my question is how can I use the same Kerberos server between the server and client site safely across the internet? And how can I keep this transparent to the clients with the introduction of Kerberos?

I plan to use RHEL for this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.